# Can a Java web app in GAE connect to Mongodb in GCE?

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I'm looking at Google app engine for deploying my Java web app which connects to a mongodb database through the mongodb java driver.

Plan 1:

1. Deploy MongoDb Database in Google Compute Engine
2. Deploy Java Web app in Google App Engine and pass the address of the MongoDb (in GCE) to the mongodb driver

Plan 2:

Deploy both Mongodb and Java web app in Google Compute engines

Question 1: Will Plan 1 work ?
Question 2: I think Plan 2 will probably work. But is it the most efficient  method ? If not, can you suggest a more efficient method?

Note: Im on planning on using Google Datastore.

Answer (score 0):

Your plan 1 is feacible, the only thing you need to ensure is that your App Engine and Compute Engine (MongoDB) are in the same virtual network. As it is stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/using-third-party-databases).

The plan 2 won't be cost effective due to the requirement of having the intance(s) running your app on 24x7. Even if there are no traffic you will have to pay for them. Google App Engine will give you the chance of having a free quota.

Comment: Plan 1 did not work. Mongo driver tried to create a separate thread for connecting with Mongo DB which GAE did not allow. I ended up having both the webapp and the mongodb in one Google Compute engine instance.